# Trying to write a file from an Azure WebJob

Tags: azure, webjob

My plan is to have the WebJob send the newly generated CSV to a blob storage where it's picked up by an Azure Function and emailed out to a group of recipients.

I'm using the [CsvWriter](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) library to generate the CSV. I'm told that ideally I should upload straight to the blob storage container, however I'm not sure how I'm going to do that when CsvWriter is only able to write to the filesystem using whatever TextWriter we pass to it through the constructor.

So what I'm trying to do instead is allow CsvWriter to write the file to the filesystem, and then I'll pick that up and upload it to the blob storage. The problem here is that every directory I try to get it to write to denies access to be WebJob. I have tried `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBJOBS_ROOT_PATH")` as well as `%HOME%` and `d:\site\wwwroot`.

What directory do I need to be writing to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid it altogether by using a `StringWriter`, you do not *have* to use the file system:

```
using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
using (var csvWriter = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(stringWriter))
{
    csvWriter.WriteComment("Test");
    csvWriter.Flush();

    var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("test.csv");
    await blob.UploadTextAsync(stringWriter.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This will work, but you’d need to account for network failures with a well thought through retry pattern.

Comment: @Josh that is correct, but this is the case for every scenario that involves network communication and as such, I see it as a seperate issue. Also not that the azure storage sdk has [built-in retry policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/retry-service-specific#azure-storage)